# Problem with the size of test data?

Tags: nlp, dataset, machine-learning-model, preprocessing

I am working on my thesis, which has two different research questions:

1. Evaluate transformer models while incorporating non textuel features
2. Evaluate the importance of data quality in tranformer models

So, I have two different datasets with various qualities.

My approach:
The validation set was created by selecting 10% of the crowdsourced dataset, while the test set consisted of 10% of the ground truth dataset.
Problem here is that the test set doesn't have much samples. Here is the distribution:

- 6 samples for label 0
- 24 samples for label 1
- 74 samples for label 2

So basically the evaluation won't be that significant, but the problem is that I can't merge both validation and test set, since I am assuming that the test data has better quality?

Does anyone have an idea how I can tackle this problem.

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't understand: are "crowdsourced dataset" and "ground truth dataset" distinct? If yes, why can't you use more of the "ground truth dataset"?